# how to programmatically click a .NET 4 WinForm TreeView TreeNode

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I need to programmatically click a treeview treenode so that the NodeClick event fires. I used to be able to call Select(), but with this version of .NET (4) that method has gone away.

Anyone know what the new approach is?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 1):

Where have you seen a Select() method on a TreeNode? I must have missed something :-)

Anyway, if you want to Select the node, you can do this:

```
TreeNode node;
node.TreeView.SelectedNode = node;
```